# Selecting the Window for "Live Visual Tree" in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, visual-tree

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution that contains 2 WPF applications. Both applications start up when I run the solution in debug mode (pressing F5). I am using the new Live Visual Tree window that comes with Visual Studio 2015 but it only presents the visual tree of one of the applications.

Is there a way to select the other visual tree, or even to view both of them at the same time?